# Search for a String inside all files inside a war

Tags: grep, java, eclipse

Where I work someone had Java project and used Eclipse to export that project into a .war package.

Now I need to search for a string inside all the files that make that .war package. I know that a .war package is just a .zip file, and I have extracted its contents, however, now I have bunch of of .class java files (among images, xmls and other stuff) and I have no idea on how to search strings inside them.

I am a Linux Mint user, so I tried using the "grep -R stringHere ." command without success (I am not an advanced user), this command only searches inside text files.

I also searched and found the [crgrep project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep/) but it is currently bugged and it does not work.

Does anyone know a linux command that can search inside all the contents of a .war package and check if those contents contain a specific string or code sample?

I really need to find a way to search through the content of the .class files. That is my only priority so far. I don't care about images nor about any other type of text files.

Comment: The .class files _are_ just text files right?

Comment: GNU grep should search binary files by default.

Comment: The .class java files are not text files as far as I know. So, it means that the command "grep -R supermario ." will also search inside the .class java files?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, it will search inside them (if it's GNU `grep`), but it will not output the _lines_ that contain the strings as there's no such thing as a _line_ in a binary file. You can use the `-a` option to override that, or you could use `grep -rao '[[:print:]]*yourString[[:print:]]*'` to output all the _printable_ characters around `yourString` that are found in the file. (you should prefer `-r` over `-R`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
find /path/to/extracted/war -name '*.class' -exec strings -f "{}" +
  |grep yourString
```

Comment: If a mint `grep -R` doesn't find it, chances are the string is not in there. However adding `-e l` or `-e b` options to `string` might bring up something if the strings are UCS2 or UTF16.